# LaunchDaemon Plist not running

Tags: launchd

I have created a plist file to launch my app (10.5 & 10.6)on the login screen, die when logging in and the respawn when the Desktop is loaded. If i place my plist file within /Library/LaunchAgents it runs correctly. If i try running it from /Library/LaunchDaemons it does not run.

As this is my first app for the Mac i am unsure of where i should be putting my plist file and what mistake i have made. I have set the ownership of my Plist file to root:wheel with the permissions -rw-r--r--

Am i right trying to run my app from LaunchDaemons or is it in fact ok to be run from LaunchAgents?

I have attached my plist below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.kezsoft.client</string>
    <key>LimitLoadToSessionType</key>
    <array>
        <string>LoginWindow</string>
        <string>Aqua</string>
    </array>
    <key>OnDemand</key>
    <false/>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Applications/kezsoft/kezsoftClient/Client.app/Contents/MacOS/Client</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Am i right trying to run my app from
>   LaunchDaemons or is it in fact ok to
>   be run from LaunchAgents?

Either is fine, but it's simpler to run from launchagents when your just getting started as fewer arguments need to be worked out correctly.

More details are in the apple deve centre documentation

- [creating a plist file](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/LaunchOnDemandDaemons.html)
- [launchd plist man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/launchd.plist)